# Process escaped text to dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, escaping

I have the text log with strings and want to convert them to dictionaries

```
log = """
{'details': "object={'id': 1}"}
{'details': 'object={\'id\': 2}'}
"""

lines = log.strip().split("\n")

for line in lines:
    dct = eval(line)
    print(f"{dct=}")
```

First line processed well to `dct={'details': "object={'id': 1}"}`

I want to process the second line to `{'details': "object={'id': 2}"}` but get the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error instead.

How to convert the strings with `\'` to dictionaries?

Comment: The problem is: this string doesn't contain backslashes. `print(log)` to see. If it *did* contain backslashes, it'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
log = r"""
{'details': "object={'id': 1}"}
{'details': 'object={\'id\': 2}'}
"""
lines = log.strip().split("\n")
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace(r"\'", '"')
    dct = eval(line)
    print(f"{dct=}")
```